# Are duplicates of string-constants in JavaScript optimized by the interpreter?

Tags: javascript, string, constants, jit

Especially when dealing with DOM objects in JavaScript, there are often duplicates of one and the same string.

Should such a string saved in a global variable (or constant) or is JavaScript optimising by itself?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you can't tell.

Comment: DOM objects are host objects anyway so we cannot tell how they are implemented. I doubt there's a lot of duplication in the data model.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is an intern pool that gets used, but this is completely implementation dependent since the ECMAScript spec. doesn't tell vendors how to implement the functionality.